# Parse Email Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the below string in a file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDARPRODID://Yahoo//Calendar
//ENVERSION:2.0METHOD:REQUESTBEGIN:VEVENTSUMMARY:Review MeetingDESCRIPTION:Testing the 
yahoomail eventCLASS:PUBLICDTSTART;TZID=Etc/GMT:20140213T163000ZDTEND;TZID=Etc
/GMT:20140213T173000ZLOCATION:ChennaiPRIORITY:0SEQUENCE:1UID:252f25fc-
a39c-4121-9835-774a6c558b33ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:aaa@aaa.comATTENDEE;
RSVP=TRUE:mailto:bbb@aaa.comATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:xxxin@yahoo.inATTENDEE;
RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test.test@test.orgATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:xxx@xxx.mailgun.orgORGANIZER;
CN=Sherin jemima G;SENT-
BY="mailto:xxxin@yahoo.in":mailto:xxxin@yahoo.inTRANSP:OPAQUEEND:VEVENTBEGIN:VTIMEZONETZID:
Europe/London+0100TZNAME:BSTDTSTART:19810329T010000RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;
BYDAY=-1SUEND:DAYLIGHTBEGIN:STANDARDTZOFFSETFROM:+0100TZOFFSETTO:+0000TZNAME:GMTDTSTART:199
61027T020000RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;
BYDAY=-1SUEND:STANDARDBEGIN:STANDARDTZOFFSETFROM:-000115TZOFFSETTO:+0000TZNAME:GMTDTSTART:1
8471201T000000RDATE:18471201T000000END:STANDARDBEGIN:DAYLIGHTTZOFFSETFROM:+0000TZOFFSETTO:+
0100TZNAME:BSTDTSTART:19160521T020000
```

**edit:** unnecessary lines cuted.

I have used file_get_contents function to read the string and used preg_match_all function to get the attendees list.

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/mailto:(.*?)(.com|.org|.net|.in)/', $convert, $emails);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($emails[0]);
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

Output:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => mailto:aaa@aaa.com
            [1] => mailto:bbb@bbb.com
            [2] => mailto:xxxin
            [3] => mailto:test.test@test.org
            [4] => mailto:xxx@xxx.mailgun.org
            [5] => mailto:xxxin
            [6] => mailto:xxxin
        )
```

Expected Output:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => mailto:aaa@aaa.com
            [1] => mailto:bbb@bbb.com
            [2] => mailto:xxxin@yahoo.in
            [3] => mailto:test.test@test.org
            [4] => mailto:xxx@xxx.mailgun.org
            [5] => mailto:xxxin@yahoo.in
            [6] => mailto:xxxin@yahoo.in
        )
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expressions is not looking for the @ sign.

This already gives better results :

```
'/mailto:(.*?)@(.*?)(\.com|\.org|\.net|\.in)/'
```

The fact to list top level domains is not a good idea. There are more than 250 country tlds, and hundreds are coming.

Your file's structure is flawed, it doesn't have a closing delimiter for an email. You have to fix this first. After that it will be possible to write a good regex parser.

Answer (score 4):

Escape the dot in the regex:

```
preg_match_all('/mailto:(.*?)(\.com|\.org|\.net|\.in)/', $convert, $emails);
```